# Is there an easier way to keyframe a curve than shape keys?

Tags: animation, keyframes, shape-keys

I have a character that I render in multiple poses. The character has a chain, and I need to make sure the chain looks correct in each pose.

[image: the model with the curve selected]

At the moment, what I do, is this:

1. Create the new pose
2. Select the curve that the chain uses in the curve modifier
3. Create a new shape key
4. Edit the curve so it fits properly
5. Keyframe the curve, so that the curve uses the correct shape key on the given frame

This is really tedious (and I'm apparently also running out of shape keys, because I have more than 799).

I'd love to simply keyframe the individual points of the curve without shape keys, so I can quickly change the shape of the chain in the same way I pose my model.

Comment: For manual keying, have a look at the **Hook** modifier.. and tutorials on controlling a curve with hooks?

Comment: @RobinBetts The issue with the hook modifier is (correct me if I’m wrong), that it doesn’t allow me to scale down or up a bezier point, so the ability to control my curve is very limited.

Comment: why don't you use physics to move the chain?

Comment: Ahhh.. OK, (again for manual keying, trying to keep it as simple as possible) check out the shipped **Animall** add-on. Still working for me in 3.41, not yet checked in later versions.

Comment: @Chris because I have lots of different poses (over 100) and I would need to use physics on each pose separately to get the result, and then somehow transfer that to the individual frames. Seems overkill, but maybe I’m missing an easy way to do this?

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann sorry if I was unclear, I’m talking about scaling and rotating bezier curve points, not the chain.

Comment: @RobinBetts Animall looks exactly what I’m after. The only downside is that it doesn’t support auto keying but I can live with that. Thanks!

Comment: @enyo Using hooks, you are able to scale the bezier handles, in proportion to the vertex. You can create individual hooks for the handles as well, for more options while animating.

Comment: @lajawi do you mind explaining a bit how I would be able to scale the handles with a single hook? I tried it and couldn’t get it to work.

Comment: @enyo You have to select the bezier vertex once, that way both handles should be selected as well. If you now create a hook, and you scale that hook, the handles will scale as well.
If you want, you can hook the vertex and two handles to separate hooks each, and then parent the handle's hooks to the vertex' hook, that way you have more freedom with animating it.

Comment: @lajawi oh nice! That’s very convenient indeed. The only thing that it doesn’t allow me to do, is to change the tilt of a curve point. Do you know if that is somehow possible without animall?

Comment: @enyo I've just tried it with drivers, and that works beatifully!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer derived from the comments:

### Hooks

One solution for animating a curve using keyframes, instead of shape keys, is using the [`Hook Modifier`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/deform/hooks.html).

[image]

#### Short list of steps

1. Select the curve points you want to create a hook for;
2. Add a hook (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> `Hook to New Object`);
3. To have a control for the tilt, add an empty;
4. <kbd>Right</kbd><kbd>Click</kbd> one of the `Rotation` `Transform` and `Copy as New Driver`;

   - Tip: lock all transforms except for the value you copied as driver!
5. Go to your curve, and select the vertex;
6. Right<kbd>Click</kbd> the `Tilt` `Transform` and choose `Paste Driver`.

You're all set! Repeat for all curve vertices.

#### Steps in full detail

To do so, go into `Edit Mode` on your curve. Then you can either select the vertex with handles and hook them:

[image: Curve vertex and handles selected]

Or you hook the vertex and handles to separate objects for more freedom (to be able to select the vertex only, you'll need to use [`Select Box`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/selecting.html#select-box) (image))

[image: Select the vertex using Box Select]

After you've selected all the points you want to hook to *one* object, go to `Control Points > Hooks > Hook to New Object` or use the the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>.

[image: Hook to New Object]

Now you've got your curve handles and/or vertices hooked to some empties. If you have an empty per point (handles separate) then it's useful to parent those to the vertex they belong to (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>).

[image: Parent empties]

To be able to `Tilt` your curve points from outside, you can use [`Drivers`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/drivers/introduction.html). You can use the existing empty to do so, but I suggest adding a new one, e.g. an `Empty Circle`. Align it to the curve point for easier use, and parent it, like the empties for the handle, to the hook of your curve point.

Then go to its `Rotation` `Transform`, right click the value you want to use as control for the `Tilt`, and select `Copy as New Driver` (small tip, lock all other transforms, as you won't be needing them on this empty).

[image: Copy as New Driver]

Final step is to paste the driver. Select your curve, go into `Edit Mode`, select the vertex you want to add this driver to, <kbd>Right</kbd><kbd>Click</kbd> on the `Tilt` `Transform`, and select `Paste Driver`.

[image: Paste Driver]

Repeat these steps for all your curve vertices for full freedom!